# persist method giving PersistentObjectException on trying to persist a new Object

Tags: java, hibernate, persist

In my below code i am trying to persist a newly created instance of Employee, it is throwing  persistantobject exception :

```
public class abc
{
   public static void main(String as[])
   {
       Configuration cfg= new Configuration();System.out.println("--------------got cfg object-----------");
       cfg = cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");System.out.println("--------------hbm loaded into cfg-----------");
       SessionFactory sf= cfg.buildSessionFactory();
       Employee item3 = new Employee();
       item3.setEid(420);
       Session session = sf.openSession(); 
       Employee item = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, new Integer(12));
      // item.setFname("myaim1"); 
      // session.save(item);

     // Integer a= (Integer)session.save(item3);
       //session.persist(item3);
       Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
       session.persist(item3);
        tx.commit(); 
       session.close(); // end of first session, item is detached  

   }}
```

And exception is :

```
-------------hbm loaded into cfg-----------
Hibernate: select employee0_.eid as eid0_0_, employee0_.first_name as first2_0_0_, employee0_.last_name as last3_0_0_, employee0_.email as email0_0_ from EMPLOYEE3 employee0_ where employee0_.eid=?
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: Employee
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:618)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:592)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:596)
    at abc.main(abc.java:23)
```

i am using hibernate core ver 4.3.
Whats gone wrong ?

Comment: Can you show the mapping of the `@Id` attribute on the `Employee` class?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason for using `persist()` here ?
Why are you not using `save()` ?

Something like this :

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

session.beginTransaction();
session.save(item3);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: i used a save and it was firing an insert ahile commiting . that is ok. But persist is something which guarantees every query at transaction commit . so i was trying persist but its throwing this exception

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error is at the line `item3.setEid(420);`. I guess you must be using `@Id` with `@GeneratedValue` with one of `SEQUENCE/IDENTITY/TABLE/AUTO'. If so, you can comment out this line as try.

If you continue to face the same issue, posting the `Employee` class would help further debug it.

Comment: i am using auto-increment generator in the hbm file , save works fine , dont know wats wrong with persist . theoritically it should work .

Comment: @jayendrabhatt please post the `Employee` class. By the way, did you try with commenting out the `item3.setEid(420);`?

Comment: @jayendrabhatt For Employee class, please include the related hbm file, if you are not using annotations on Employee class. Also which database are you testing against?